# Magento 2: I want to change "MOSTVIEWED" to laptop category products in home page layout

Tags: magento2, layout, products, home-page

"MOSTVIEWED" to "Laptop category" how can i do that ??

I tried to create block and insert it into

> app/design/frontend/mytheme/Magento_Theme/layout
>
> app/design/frontend/mytheme/Plazathemes_Layout/layout

still I can not get

[image]